# Appending multiple arrays into a list in Python

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have two arrays `A1` and `A2` with shapes `(1,3)` and `(1,4)` respectively. I want to append these two arrays into a list. I present the expected output.

```
import numpy as np
A1=np.array([[128, 129, 131]])
A2=np.array([[128, 131, 132, 140]])
```

The expected output is

```
A=[array([[128, 129, 131]]), array([[128, 131, 132, 140]])]
```

Comment: `[A1,A2]` is all you need

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! It is helpful to show what you have already tried based on your own research and describe what went wrong with your attempts so that we can better understand how to give specific help.

Comment: you can also use A.append(A1) A.append(A2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `numpy` allows fast numerical manipulations it expects all the arrays to be of the same shape, so in your case (i.e., `A1.shape = 3` and `A2.shape = 4`) you won't be able to convert the combined array into `numpy`. The only thing you can do is to use the `python` `list` object, as pointed by @hapulj by:

```
C = [A1, A2]
```

but it certainty be slower than using `numpy` due to the header appended by `python` to represent the objects in the list ([more on that here](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/02.01-understanding-data-types.html)), so I'd recommend making sure your arrays are of the same length (e.g., by adding `0` if it make sense in your case), and then using something like:

```
import numpy as np
A1=np.array([[128, 129, 131, 0]])
A2=np.array([[128, 131, 132, 140]])

C  = np.array([A1, A2], dtype=np.int16)
```

Output:

```
array([[[128, 129, 131,   0]],

       [[128, 131, 132, 140]]], dtype=int16)
```

Cheers